# conforming if a preference is added or not in android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

i am trying to store a preference in "pref.xml" file.i used the following code to do that.

```
SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences(pref_file,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor add=pref.edit();
        add.putString("password",usrpass);
```

now i want to check wether it is stored or not.how can i do that. i dont want to do that in my code. i just want to check it manually in my file.
my file after running code looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <CheckBoxPreference android:defaultValue="true"
             android:key="@string/first"/>
        <Preference android:key="@string/pass"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

here i cant see any value of password stored.
Any suggestion regarding this .

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing any change in the "pref.xml", is that it's simply a resource file for building the (visual) preference screen.

The actual preferences are saved in a file called "pref_file" (or what ever you decide to call it), which is located in the folder "/data/data/(app package name)/shared_prefs/".

To extract it, you can use adb (in the Android SDK subfolder "platform-tools") with the command "pull"...

Here is a small Windows BAT script I made to simplify the job:

```
    @echo off
    title Retrieve application preferences
    cd C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
    adb pull "/data/data/com.tovine.alcotool/shared_prefs/com.tovine.alcotool_preferences.xml" "C:\Android\Extracted app data\shared_prefs.xml"
    echo Application preferences extracted, see "Extracted app data" folder
    pause
    exit
```

You may modify it to suit your app and use it freely, if you want to... :)